# Looking for simple contract template for making website. Stuck on termination clause?

Tags: contracts, freelance-websites, web-development

I am making a simple website for a friend of a friend. We have agreed on an hourly rate. I'm just wondering, how does a contract normally end? It could have a term like "either party can terminate this contract by providing 7 days notice". But that doesn't seem to cover the case where the website is completed and their naturally is no more work.

What if a long time from now she comes back to give me more work on the website but I am too busy with other projects, how is that prevented in terms of stating the scope in a contract?

Answer (score 2):

How do you define the website is done in the contract as-is? Does it need to have feature X, Y and Z to be considered done? Or does it need the client to say "OK, you're done"?

What you're looking to get is an exit clause. Put it in all your contracts. It's the definitive way to make sure you and your client know when the current job is completed.

Items to include in your clause:

- Client chooses to end relationship
- You choose to end the relationship

  - How much notice is needed?
  - What happens to currently-worked on assets?
  - How far to the next milestone for payment?
  - Does there need to be a certain reason?
- Project is completed

  - What are the milestones? How are they quantitatively measured?
- Project is not completed

  - Why not, and can the contract be picked up at a later time with the same terms?
  - Includes for non-payment of your milestones

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a [Catch-22](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/simple-catch-22-examples.html) situation? Part of what I'd like to invoice for is helping the client decide what features the website must or should have. So how would I have the client sign a contract before the work starts that would specify what features the website would have?

Comment: Your contract and Scope of Work (SoW) are two different documents. If you're concerned they won't end the agreement when you believe it should be, then it needs to be spelled out **completely** in your contract. You can always have additional contracts for the actual work portion, vs the consulting portion, if you wish.